# How to initialize another form from TForm1.FormCreate?

Tags: delphi

My application has multiple forms. I load all settings at TForm1.FormCreate (Main Form). I have my configuration panel in form8.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  settings:=TMemIniFile.Create('');
  settings.Create('settings.ini');

  if settings.ReadString('settings','ComboBox1','')='1' then 
  form1.ComboBox1.checked:=true else form1.ComboBox1.checked:=false;


  //line below crashes application because form8 has not been initialized yet
  if settings.ReadString('settings','ComboBox2','')='1' then 
  form8.ComboBox1.checked:=true else form8.ComboBox1.checked:=false;

  settings.free
end;
```

Is there any way to force initialization of form8 so I can configure UI elements there? I would really prefer to do that from TForm1.FormCreate. Yes I know that I could load settings from form1.Onshow or form1.Onactivate but this time I need to put code in form1.Oncreate because my application also starts minimized in tray.

Comment: Declare a constructor that receives the necessary information.

Comment: Indeed, instead of making your main form manage the display of other forms, do it the other way around. Other forms should *read from* the main form. Or better yet, from an object in the background which is shared globally for the entire application.

Comment: The references to form1 in TForm1.FormCreate is bad practice - use `ComboBox1.Checked := True`. This will always refer to the current instance of TForm1, not a specific instance. Also the entire block can be replaced with `ComboBox1.Checked := settings.ReadString('settings', 'ComboBox1','') = '1'`

Answer (score 2):

Move that settings display code to your settings form (e.g. create method into which you pass the config object). And create and display that settings form only when it's needed. There's no need to have prepared but hidden settings form (not speaking about its possible synchronization when the settings object change).

One idea, not *ideal* though:

```
type
  TFormConfig = class(TForm)
    CheckBoxSomething: TCheckBox;
  private
    procedure DisplaySettings(ASettings: TMemIniFile);
    procedure CollectSettings(ASettings: TMemIniFile);
  public
    class function Setup(AOwner: TComponent; ASettings: TMemIniFile): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

class function TFormConfig.Setup(AOwner: TComponent; ASettings: TMemIniFile): Boolean;
var
  Form: TFormConfig;
begin
  { create the form instance }
  Form := TFormConfig.Create(AOwner);
  try
    { display settings }
    Form.DisplaySettings(ASettings);
    { show form and store the result }
    Result := Form.ShowModal = mrOK;
    { and collect the settings if the user accepted the dialog }
    if Result then
      Form.CollectSettings(ASettings);
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormConfig.DisplaySettings(ASettings: TMemIniFile);
begin
  CheckBoxSomething.Checked := ASettings.ReadBool('Section', 'Ident', True);
end;

procedure TFormConfig.CollectSettings(ASettings: TMemIniFile);
begin
  ASettings.WriteBool('Section', 'Ident', CheckBoxSomething.Checked);
end;
```

And its usage:

```
if TFormConfig.Setup(Self, Settings) then
begin
  { user accepted the config dialog, update app. behavior if needed }
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

place your settings code within the DPR:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);

  // place settings code here

  Application.Run;
end.
```